# Modification of related(featured) products in Wordpress / E-Commerce

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I need help with the following problem:

A customer wants to attach to a certain product, featured products of his choice, not choose automatically. For example:

PAGE of product A <- attached related products A / B / C (chosen/set by customer).

Now my quesions:

1) Is there already a plugin that has a feature of choosing which related products should displayed at certain PRODUCT PAGE ?

2) If there is no such a plugin as in point no 1 - can anybody show the direction and hints how to best get to this problem ...

Answer (score 0):

If you use the WooCommerce plugin, you can use the [Composite Products Extension](http://www.woothemes.com/products/composite-products/) to provide this feature. It's a paid extension, but it allows customers to choose a related product which they want to purchase, from a set of options you provide.

Hope this helps.